# FreeMarker specifc table index from results

Tags: spring, freemarker

I'm using openReports that uses freeMarker formats as a template.

The following:

```
<@display.table name="results" class="displayTag" sort="list" export=true pagesize=10 requestURI="queryReportResult.action">    
<@display.column property="first_name" title="First Name" sortable=true headerClass="sortable" />
<@display.column property="last_name" title="Last Name" sortable=true headerClass="sortable"/>
</@display.table>
```

The data is automatically grabbed using a stored procedure.
This will create a sortable table, does anyone know how I could access just the first row of data. I intend to save it into a variable and output it in some part of the page.

The reason I want to do this is we have a basic report and what would make it perfect is if I could print some from it toward the top of the page above the report.

I know a lot of people aren't familiar with OpenReports, but I figured freeMarker does have a pretty good following. I understand if this is pretty obscure

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see from here, the `@display.table` call prints the whole table at once, so there's nowhere to insert the FreeMarker code to catch the first row. But of course you should check the documentation of `@display.table` to see if it offers any helpful options. But, I suppose you have already done that. So as a last resort, you can capture the whole table into a variable with `<#assign tableHTML><@display.table ...>...</@display.table></#assign>` and then extract the first row with a regular expression (or something like that) from the value of the `tableHTML` variable.

Comment: Thanks man, I'll give it a try. This was along the lines of what I am looking for. I did check the documentation, the assign method makes sense. I'm just looking to read the data another way so I can grab desired parts of this table.